# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of IonApp which is inside StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks, ionic5, ionic-react

findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of IonApp which is inside StrictMode

I am getting this error when Using any of the IONIC UI components like IonApp or IonButton in the react project. Moreover, removing the strict mode is also throwing an error.

However on using ionic ion-app tag instead of IONAPP is not throwing this error!!

Comment: [Material-UI's](https://material-ui.com/) having [same issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/183f267fa5995ea2c6c2abd4517164204e74382e/docs/src/pages/guides/migration-v4/migration-v4.md#non-ref-forwarding-class-components). Seems like most [React](https://reactjs.org/) libraries are running into this. But, it's still good to have articles calling libraries out on this.

Comment: Do you have an example code sandbox you'd be willing to share toward the conversation ?